# i dont understand why this background dont get painted

Tags: css

I have two problems. The first thing is that when I hover over one thing (https://prnt.sc/s9etq3 (the mouse isnt visible because of the screenshot but it is on the object)) I only get an outline and not the full background. The second thing is that I'm too stupid to scale the search box right. I want that it's 10% away from the sides (left and right). The code for the hovering is inside `div.gallery:hover`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

*{
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}



.search_box{
  position: relative;   
  left: 0%;
}

.search_box input[type="text"]{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.fa-search{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  .search_box{
    width: 95%;
  }
}
div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #404040;
    background: #404040;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container
{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div
{
    margin: 10px;
}
.container div label
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container div label input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: none;
}
.container div label span
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #424242;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container div label span:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.container div label input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span
{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="search_box">
                <input type="text" name="box" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
});
</script>
´´´
```

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: Your hover is in media (max-width: 425px) which won't have effect on larger screen sizes.

Comment: its a php file but it should load without the other files.

Comment: what did i have to change to solve it. it worked before i added the search bar

Comment: Take it out of hover (move up) above media query. So it work for all screen sizes.